# how to make <svg> 100% width

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to make this `<svg>` element stretch to 100% of the screen width:

```
  <svg height="100" width="100">
   <path d="M0 0 L100 0 L50 100 Z" />
  </svg>
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The viewBox defines the co-ordinates you can see. Height and width define the size of the SVG. E.g.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100"  preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <path d="M0 0 L100 0 L50 100 Z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to define the html and body in CSS? As in, why can't I just write width="100%" height="100%" in the code and that's it?

Comment: Because Stack Snippets runs the SVG within an HTML container.

Comment: Also note that `viewBox` is **case sensitive** (unlike regular HTML attributes).

Comment: `preserveAspectRatio="none"` was the key to solving my problem.

Comment: This doesn't work at all.

Comment: doesnt work man